# why to create type of parent class to store the object of child class?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I am little confused about polymorphism, inheritance in C#.
While learning about polymorphism, I found something like this ParentClass P = new ChildClass(); which is a bit confusing. Why would someone create type of parent class to store the object of child class? However it is valid in c# I just want to understand 3 things:
1.  What is the purpose of doing this?
2.  What are the advantages of doing this?
3.  When we should create object like this?
Below is my code for reference:

```
using System;

class ParentClass
{
    public void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Display method in Parent class");
    }
}

class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
    public void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Display method in Child class");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ParentClass P = new ChildClass();
        P.Display();
    }
}
```

The output of the code is:
Display method in Parent class.

Now if someone has to call method in parent class why not simply create 
ParentClass P = new ParentClass();
Or if someone has to call method in Child class why not simply create 
ChildClass C = new ChildClass();

Have gone through lot of forums, still not found the answer I want. Please if anyone can explain in detail with example would be great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The whole idea of polymorphism is the possibility of creating objects from the derived class type but treat them as the base class type.

The advantage of this, is for example, lets say you have a method which gets a dozen of animals objects.
Of course, some of them are dogs, cats, birds and ect

In order to work on those objects without having to check their type, you can just treat them as the Animal base class and not with their created type class.

So you can just get a List of Animals in the method, and don't need to be worry of the objects type.

Although they all were created to a different object type, they all derives from Animal class, so they share some methods and properties.

Comment: Hey Thanks Ron F for ur answer i am getting a little bit,  but if can explain in detail with example as u said about dozen of animals objects would be great help for me

Answer (score 1):

I can give a simple example that opened my eyes as I was in your position.
Let's say we want to calculate the Area of some 2D shapes:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Shape> shapes = new List<Shape>()
        {
            new Rectangle(5, 5),
            new Circle(2)
        };

        foreach (Shape shape in shapes) //even though we just have a "Shape" here the respective methods of "Rectangle" and "Circle" are executed
        {
            Console.WriteLine(shape.CalculateArea());
        }

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}

public abstract class Shape
{
    public abstract double CalculateArea();
}

public class Rectangle : Shape
{
    private double a;
    private double b;

    public Rectangle(double a, double b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public override double CalculateArea()
    {
        return a * b;
    }
}

public class Circle : Shape
{
    private double r;

    public Circle(double r)
    {
        this.r = r;
    }

    public override double CalculateArea()
    {
        return 2 * Math.PI * r;
    }
}
```

As you can see we have a parent class of `Shape` and derive `Rectangle` and `Circle` from it. Because we tell C# with `public abstract double ClaculateArea()` all subclasses have to implement such a function. This calculation will most likely be different for every subclass we create. The gain in doing it like this is that we can save all sorts of different Shapes that derive from `Shape` inside a List. But if we call `CalculateArea()` of these items which **subclass-types are unknown at this point** the respective calculation functions will be executed.

Be aware that this is only one example how such constructucs are useful but in my opinion this is the most obvious and easy to understand one.

Answer (score 0):

By allowing us to upcast child classes as a more derived class or base class we can create collections of base class that could contain elements that are more derived. Look below at this in action using a `Cat` and `Dog` class that both inherit from a base `Animal` class:

```
Cat c = new Cat();
Dog d = new Dog();

List<Animal> myPets = new List<Animal>();
myPets.Add(c);
myPets.Add(d); //no casting needed
```

So say that the `Animal` base has a property that holds the age:

```
public int Age { get; set; }
```

Because we have implicitly said that the my `Cat` c and `Dog` d are of type `Animal`, we can call this type without doing any casting, which is useful.

```
Foreach(Animal a in myPets)
   Console.WriteLine(a.Age);
```

This is useful for maybe collections of controls where we have a `asp:Panel` in Asp.Net or a `Panel` in winforms that contain children (which could be a collection of `label`, `textbox`, etc) instead of containing a `List` of each of these items we can upcast these to a base that they all share which is the `Control` class allowing us to have a collection of child items or nodes held as a collection of `Controls` and when we want to do some operation we can downcast it to it's more derived type (using `as`/`is`)

This is also useful in delegates, when creating a delegate we can assign a more derived type than what it returns making is reusable for multiple different types. This is the same for collections of generic type. You should read more at the link because it has great examples.

This is covariance and contravariance

> In C#, covariance and contravariance enable implicit reference conversion for array types, delegate types, and generic type arguments.Covariance preserves assignment compatibility and contravariance reverses it.

[Further reading](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq/)

Answer (score 0):

1.The purpose, a)you will have to call child class constructor then parent class members,

2.Advantages, a)For calling child class constructor.

3.When To Use, a)When you need to access for child class constructor first and then parent class members.

**Code**

```
class ParentClass
{
    public void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Display method in Parent class");//second get executed
    }
}

class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
    public ChildClass(string x)//first get executed
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
    public void Display1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Display method in Child class");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ParentClass P = new ChildClass("First get Executed");
        P.Display();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some Limitations. It may not be a right way to Call DerivedClasses/Child Class via Parent. I leave it to self-interpretation whether it is a drawback or a limitation

Eventually Making Parent and Derived Class in One Project
and Another class having the property of type ParentClass

and Making all Parent and Child Class Internal

```
using System;


namespace Logic
{
    public class IndraDhanush
    {
        public Vehicle[] VehiclesLocal { get; set; }

        public IndraDhanush(Vehicle[] vehicles)
        {
            this.VehiclesLocal = vehicles;
        }
    }
    internal class Vehicle
    {
    }
    internal class FourWheeler : Vehicle
    {
    }
    internal class Car : FourWheeler
    {
    }
    internal class PetrolCar : Car
    {
    }
    internal class ElectricCar : Car
    {
    }
}
```

Now Refer to this Class Library in another Project
Now Make an Object of the Class which stores Parent class as Class Member

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IndraDhanush indraDhanush = new IndraDhanush(new Vehicle[] { new Vehicle(), new FourWheeler(), new Car(), new ElectricCar() });
    }
```

Well, we can try to avoid this situation > we can try to make Vehicle Class Public but still it not help to access Child class.

Adding Code in Image format as well. [Image for Both Projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYMtv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking this question because I am also confuse about that concept.

When we need dynamic instance of child class based on some condition then we can use this kind of concept. I was learning factory pattern and I found something related with this topic. I hope you'll clear you doubt.

Parent class allows later instantiation to subclasses means the creation of an object is done when it is required.

```
public interface IFactory
{
    void Drive(int miles);
}

public class Scooter : IFactory
{
    public void Drive(int miles)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Drive the Scooter : " + miles.ToString() + "km");
    }
}

public class Bike : IFactory
{
    public void Drive(int miles)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Drive the Bike : " + miles.ToString() + "km");
    }
}

public abstract class VehicleFactory
{
    public abstract IFactory GetVehicle(string Vehicle);

}

public class ConcreteVehicleFactory : VehicleFactory
{
    public override IFactory GetVehicle(string Vehicle)
    {
        switch (Vehicle)
        {
            case "Scooter":
                return new Scooter();
            case "Bike":
                return new Bike();
            default:
                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Vehicle '{0}' cannot be created", Vehicle));
        }
    }
}
```